# Namespaces in Imports field not imported from: ‘rlang’ ‘shinydashboard’, Should I write @importFrom rlang rlang or @importFrom rlang

Tags: r, package, github-pages, cran

When I do `devtool::check(cran=TRUE)` and `rhub::check()`, it shows

```
R CMD check results 
0 errors| 0 warnings| 0 notes.
```

However, when this package be upload to CRAN, it said

```
Check Details
Version: 0.2.0
Check: dependencies in R code
Result: NOTE
    Namespaces in Imports field not imported from:
     ‘rlang’ ‘shinydashboard’
     All declared Imports should be used.
```

I checked on which part I used ‘rlang’ and ‘shinydashboard’.

Turns out it's in `package_name/inst/shiny/app/ui.R`, not in the `package_name/R`

I tried to add `#' @importFrom shinydashboard shinydashboard` and
`#' @importFrom rlang rlang` in `package_name/inst/shiny/app/ui.R` and run `devtools::document()` to update `namespace`, however, these 2 functions does not appear at all.

So instead, I add these 2 `#' @importFrom`  to `package_name/R`, then `namespace` be updated.

**1. I wonder is that means I can only use `@importFrom` in a `package_name/R`**

**2. I use library(shinydashboard) and turns out its package called shinydashboard, so should I write `#' @importFrom shinydashboard shinydashboard` or `#' @importFrom shinydashboard`** **

**3. When I upload this change on the CRAN, should I change package version from 0.2.0 to 0.2.1 or should I keep 0.2.0.**

**4. Why `devtool::check(cran=TRUE)` cannot help me figure out such problem?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could move `rlang` and `shinydashboard` to the `Suggests` section of your description file.

Comment: Also, when I upload this change on the CRAN, should I change package version from 0.2.0 to 0.2.1 or should I keep 0.2.0? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you mean I do not need to add the name of the package in Namespace file with importFrom? But if so, the namespace does not change at all. But as the NOTES shows, this need to fix.

Comment: If you already have the package on cran you should update the version number. Is the app the main point of your package? If it is not I would just write library(rlang/shinydashboard) at the beginning of the app file.

Comment: And yes, you do not need to add the name of the package. To generate a new namespace, remove the importFrom statements and run devtools::document(). If this does not update the Namespace, delete it and run devtools::document() again.